# How remember the radio button choice when re-open the application on android

Tags: android, radio-button, checked

in my application i've got 3 radio buttons.. I would when i re-open the application the radio button i checked before would be still checked. Is possbile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OnCreate()

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
int savedRadioIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX, 0);
RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);
```

On OnCheckedChangeListener of radio button call the method like "SavePreferences"

```
SavePreferences("SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX", checkedIndex);
```

Write down the method

```
private void SavePreferences(String key, int value){
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
  editor.putInt(key, value);
  editor.commit(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**save state** before application close

```
 if(rbOne.isChecked())
 {
  saveCheckedRadioButtton("1");
 }
 else if(rbTwo.isChecked())
 {
  saveCheckedRadioButtton("2");
 }
 else if(rbThree.isChecked())
 {
  saveCheckedRadioButtton("3");
 }
```

This is the **code for SharedPreferences:**

```
SharedPreferences spRadio; // class variable

spRadio = context.getSharedPreferences("Your_pref_name",0);

public void saveCheckedRadioButtton(String strRB) 
{
    spRadio.edit().putString("checked_radio", strRB).commit();
}

public String getCheckedRadioButtton()
{
    return spRadio.getString("checked_radio", "");
}
```

**get the checked radio button state** using getCheckedRadioButtton() and set it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a flag in shared preferences to save and initialize the value,
I hope that it will work , as it works in my app too.